# SetInterval и время

Tags: javascript

Есть очень простое, еще даже не работающее меню, в нем открывается подменю. Высота подменю может быть разная. Эффект открытия я делаю через SetInterval, но почему-то оно происходит очень медленно. Почему?

```
i = 0;
t = setInterval(function() {
    submenu.style.height = i + 'px';
    if (i == h) { //h - высота, которую нужно достигнуть.
       clearInterval(t);
    }
    i++;
}, 1);
```

То есть как сказать: 1 - отвечает за частоту, скажем, кадров, а за счет того, что высота разная, мне кажется, оно и медленно открывает.
То есть вопрос такой: как сделать, чтобы с разной высотой, оно открывало за одно и тоже время?

Comment: css анимацией?

Comment: @andrey3, делайте инкремент не на единичку, а на двойку, тройку... И условие поставьте "больше или равно"

    if(i >= h) {
       // ...
       i += 2;
    }

Comment: @Deonis спасибо

Answer (score 1):

а документацию почитать слабо?... 
1 - это не частота кадров, а время повторения запуска данной функции в МИЛЛИСЕКУНДАХ, это раз, а два - для анимационных эффектов следует использовать setTimeout. 
Почитайте про jQuery, что ли..